# How to 301 Redirects on new site when old site lost due to Host crush

Tags: 301-redirect, godaddy

My Host (WHC) had a "Major incident" and all my Wordpress website data lost.
the backup copy was on that server as well.

I moved the domain to Godaddy and want to rebuild this lost site in their Go Central builder.

How can I redirect 301 to a different link (new CMS not allow more than 25 characters on page name) when there is no old website?

The domain stays the same, but was moved to a different host (Godaddy)

Comment: You will need to set up these redirects entirely within your new CMS. For instance, 301 `https://example.com/long-link-from-old-web-host/` to `https://example.com/new-short-link/`. Depending on your new CMS, the process for this will differ.

Comment: Be careful of site-builders.  You will be stuck with godaddy forever, or if you decide (like many) that godaddy sucks, you will have to rebuild from scratch - you won't be able to export your site.  You are better off going with a more open solution such as WordPress or Drupal.

Comment: Go Central may not support redirects.  I haven't been able to find any information on how to create them with that platform with some quick Google searches.